# Системный файл формы системной безопасности

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, консоль

Помогите найти системный файл, который использует форму предупреждения системной безопасности, реагируя на открытие помеченных файлов как защищенные от запуска.

Есть необходимость реагировать на запуск помеченных файлов через свое приложение. Например, блокировать запуск .exe расширений, с возможностью их запустить. При этом не мешая работать системе, т.е. система должна реагировать только на помеченные заблокированные файлы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вполне понимаю, что именно вам надо от этого окна.

Comment: Заменить его на свою форму, чтобы приложение могло управлять запуском файла.

Comment: Вам это нужно для любых файлов в системе?

Comment: Да, для всех помеченных заблокированных файлов.

Comment: Так, а чем помеченный файл отличается от заблокированного?

Comment: При скачивании файла с интернета он маркируется для защиты таким образом, я просто использую для этого термина два слова, помеченный и заблокированный т.к. в таких файлах присутствует кнопка "Разблокировать". Система перед запуском файла каким-то образом сначала обращается к системе безопасности, вот это обращение я и ищу, чтобы внедрить свое приложение.

Comment: Хм... эта штука называется SmartScreen, и активируется она, походу, через DCOM. А вот дальше я не знаю.

Comment: Вам надо добавить к нужному файлу дополнительный NTFS-поток с именем `Zone.Identifier:$DATA` и содержимым `[ZoneTransfer]\r\nZoneId=3` (`\r\n` здесь - это перевод строки). См. [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn392609.aspx).

Comment: @Yaant во-первых, `:$DATA` - это тип потока, а не часть имени. Во-вторых, он уже признался что ему нужно не файлы помечать, а перехватывать их запуск. Т.е. он хочет заменить своей программой SmartScreen.

Comment: @PavelMayorov А, тип, так тип :) Был не в курсе таких деталей NTFS. А насчет перехвата запуска, из формулировки вопроса мне это показалось неочевидным. Я понял так, что автору хочется расширить стандартный функционал для произвольных файлов. :)